# GetUIkit3 Sortable: Callback

Tags: javascript, php, server, getuikit, sortables

I would like to use UIkit3's sortable to display thumbnails of images and then allow the user to re-order them by dragging/dropping them around. Once completed, I would like the user to press a button, which then calls a PHP function on the server with the the filenames of the images in the sorted order. How does that call look like on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use UIkit util to react when sortable stops, that means you finished sorting.

```
var util = UIkit.util;

util.ready(function () {
    util.on(document.body, 'stop', function (e, sortable, el) {
        console.log(e.type, sortable, el); //this if for the reference
        //get the elements order in your grid
        var sortResult = { elementsOrder: [] };
        $('#myGridWithElements > div').each(function () {
            var currentEl = $(this)
            var currentElSrc = $('img', currentEl).attr('src'); //src of image inside the div context
            sortResult.elementsOrder.push(currentElSrc);  
        });

        $.post( "/admin/save_order",{data: sortResult}).done(function( data ) {
            alert('Yes, you\'ve saved the data');
        }).fail(function(data) { alert('Something gone wrong');});
    });
});
```

I've got inspired with the sortable test page https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/tests/sortable.html

Comment: Thanks, corrected typo. If you don't want to save immediately - you can attach on click event to a button - "Save" and just copy the code between `util.on({})` braces. It should work even with any other sorting library. It's just a proposition how to pass the data of the current image's order inside the div.

Comment: You are too fast :) Apologies for pestering, I am a backend person, not a frontend and I am somewhat sorry to as a basic question but where must the myGridWithElements go in the list of images?

    <ul class="uk-grid-match uk-child-width-1-2 uk-child-width-1-5@m" uk-sortable="handle: .uk-card" uk-grid id="myGridWithElements">
 <li>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body">
   <img src="sort.jpeg" width="40" alt="XX">
  </div>
 </li>
 
 <li>
  <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body">
   <img src="sort1.jpeg" width="80" alt="YY">
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>

Comment: As a side comment, cssBlaster21895: If you had to build a simple app that allows you to upload images (it should resize on the client side before uploading), then allows to remove and add images as well as sorting them (when they are already on the server), what would you use? I currently have a simple web-app at https://book.mercator.li which uses dropzone for the client side scaling and uploading. I can remove uploaded images but I cannot order them - the latter is a major drawback that I would like to overcome.

Comment: about the targeting div, your idea is ok - it has to be a wrapping element, so in your situation it could be ` $('#myGridWithElements > li)` rather then div.

Comment: there is plenty of libraries for sorting, https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable - with jquery, or http://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/ https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/ - without jquery , I see you use bootstrap in your applications, adding another framework would be an overkill, just choose library that will fit you